# How to write Controller in GRAV CMS

Tags: php, grav

I created a form and want to save submitted data in back-end

```
//front-end

{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action="savedata">
        <input type=text name="data">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

//back-end

function savedata()
{
    echo 'saved data:'.$_POST['data'];
    exit;
}
```

I expect the code like this

```
$grav->post('/savedata', DataController->savedata);
```

But I cannot found any tutorial about custom Controller in documentation

How can I achieve this purpose?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I think there is no way to write custom Controller, May be I should write plugin